# hybrid app and google analytics/ firebase

Tags: firebase, analytics, hybrid

My service is composed as follows:
- website (Google Analytics installed)
- hybrid app that has a webview and native page either(firebase installed)

Because of app has some webview and some native page either, 
I presume that would double check the app users

What might be a good way to know website user and appuser seperately?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use diferent sessionID's keys for the user using website and App users.
You should create a pageview event in both Web and app, for Web you can use sessionID as a Custom Dimension and for the app you should use it a custom parameter in the firebase log event. So you will have something like this:

**Web**: Timestamp + mathrandom

**App**: Timestamp